# Is it possible to replace for(auto i=0;i<n;i++) ... with a for(auto i:<something>) without using a vector?

Tags: c++

I would like to replace a simple for loop of the form:

```
for (auto i=0;i<n;i++) {
  whatever;
}
```

with an iterator of the form:

```
for (auto i: <something>) ...
```

I know it can be done with a vector, but I don't want to have to declare
a vector (and fill it).

In theory I would like something as simple as like:

```
for (auto i: 1..n) ...
```

is this possible?

thank you.

Comment: Possible? Yes, of course. Built-in? Not yet.

Comment: That rather looks like a Matlab or Java `for` loop, but not C++.

Comment: I'm curious to know *what problem is being solved* that would make it easier to do the latter rather than the former. [Range-for](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) is just that: a for-loop construct over an object that exposes a range via a `begin()` and `end()` construct. If you want to do that with a trivial numeric sequence, writing an object that does it wouldn't be difficult. But again, *why bother*?

Comment: the reason is that I feel that the typical for loop is error prone: you need to increment the control variable. But the alternative, using a range seems to require to define an array as long as the number of times the for loop will iterate. But the true reason is that I am teaching C++ to first year students and felt that avoiding the old traditional C for loop would be useful.

Comment: This has been asked many times before. Did you search?

Comment: @dmg I don't really understand how it could be error prone? And why not teach the "old traditional C loop"? A for loop is a for loop...

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit It would be helpful to flag it as a dupe, then.

Comment: @dmg Enjoy the clarity of the original for loop. Sure, you get < and <= messed up from time to time, but then, it's easy to spot and to understand. In contrast, with all those "sequences/ranges" the code is not expressing whether the bounds are included or not, or if the second number gives the length.

Comment: No comment votes left today, so just to say, I can't agree enough with WhozCraig and Elko here.

Comment: @Eiko: Of course it would, but that would require going off to find the duplicate. I'd rather the OP did that. I have other things to do!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no built-in solution.

If you want to, you can use [Boost.counting_range](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/ranges/counting_range.html) like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/range/counting_range.hpp>

int main() {
    for (auto v : boost::counting_range(2,13))
        std::cout << v << "\n";
}
```

[(live)](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f1ae7ba190a97694) or roll your own. The boost range will not save all the numbers, but wrap a pair of iterators. (Conceptually similar to the Python2 `xrange` or the Python3 `range`.)

Now whether or not this is easier/better than just writing the loop by hand is for the reader to decide.

---

Addendum: If you want to roll your own solution, write some iterator that returns a number on dereference, increases the internal number on increment and compares equal if the internal numbers are equal. Then write a wrapper class that provides `begin` and `end` functions to return such iterators.

[Boost.counting_iterator](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/iterator/doc/counting_iterator.html) is an implementation for such an iterator, and Boost.counting_range wraps it as a range as shown above.

Answer (score 7):

```
template<class T>
struct index_it{
  T t;
  void operator++(){++t;}
  T operator*()const{ return t; }
  friend bool operator==(index_it const& lhs,index_it const& rhs){
    return lhs.t==rhs.t;
  }
  friend bool operator!=(index_it const& lhs,index_it const& rhs){
    return lhs.t!=rhs.t;
  }
};
template<class T>
index_it<T> index(T t){return {t}; }
```

This is a very minimal index "iterator".  It is not really an iterator because it violates their axioms: but it is guaranteed to be sufficient for a `for(:)` loop.

```
template<class It>
struct range_t{
  It b,e;
  It begin()const{return b;}
  It end()const{return e;}
};
template<class It>
range_t<It> range(It b, It e){ return {b,e}; }
```

Is a very minimal range that qualifies for a `for(:)` loop.

```
template<class Scalar>
auto indexes(Scalar b, Scalar e){
  return range(index(b),index(e));
}
```

Makes a range of indexes.

Use:

```
for(auto i:indexes<int>(0,n))
```

For fun this also gives us:

```
template<class R>
auto iterators(R& r){
  using std::begin; using std::end;
  return indexes( begin(r), end(r) );
}
```

Which lets you iterate over the valid iterators of a container or range, just like that.  The problem is the same one once you work out what `index_it` really is!

```
for(auto it:iterators(vec))
```

[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5b6e6ada014a7205).

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in solution for this. That's all.

---

You can define something similar for your own as it follows:

```
#include<functional>
#include<cstddef>
#include<array>
#include<iostream>

template<std::size_t... I>
constexpr auto seq(std::integer_sequence<std::size_t, I...>) {
    return std::array<std::size_t, sizeof...(I)>{ I... };
}

template<std::size_t N>
constexpr auto seq() {
    return seq(std::make_index_sequence<N>());
}

int main() {
    for(auto i: seq<10>()) {
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
    }
}
```

If you want to deal with ranges other than 0 to N, you can do this instead:

```
#include<functional>
#include<cstddef>
#include<array>
#include<iostream>

template<std::size_t N, std::size_t... I>
constexpr auto seq(std::integer_sequence<std::size_t, I...>) {
    return std::array<std::size_t, sizeof...(I)>{ (N+I)... };
}

template<std::size_t N, std::size_t M, std::enable_if_t<(N<M)>* = nullptr>
constexpr auto seq() {
    return seq<N>(std::make_index_sequence<M-N>());
}

int main() {
    for(auto i: seq<3, 7>()) {
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Note that this solution requires C++14 revision.

---

Another solution that doesn't require to instantiate a data structure is the following one:

```
#include<functional>
#include<cstddef>
#include<array>
#include<iostream>
#include<utility>

template<std::size_t N, typename F, std::size_t... I>
constexpr void seq(F &&f, std::integer_sequence<std::size_t, I...>) {
    int arr[] = { (std::forward<F>(f)(I+N), 0)... };
}

template<std::size_t N, std::size_t M, typename F, std::enable_if_t<(N<M)>* = nullptr>
constexpr void seq(F &&f) {
    seq<N>(std::forward<F>(f), std::make_index_sequence<M-N>());
}

int main() {
    seq<3, 7>([](int i){ 
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
    });
}
```

Likely `arr` will be wiped out by the compiler, but it looks a bit less like a for loop.

Comment: Thanks for your solution. This solution, however, also needs a data structure of size equal to the range (the array, instead of vector). I think the main disadvantage of this is the need to allocate as many elements as iterations in the loop.

Comment: @dmg Updated the question. Another way is to define a custom iterable data structure for which `begin` and `end` exist, then use it. Anyway, here are a bunch of proposals. Pick your preferred one up if you find them interesting, otherwise they will be there for future readers.